# how to remove or change icon from share sheet android

Tags: android, share, android-sharesheet

I want remove or add the app icon to be shown when sharing inside my app. When clicking the Share the App button in my App. It works but in some samsungs device it visible icon. It shows like Below[image]

how can i remove or change icon. thanks

Comment: Were you able to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

thats design of Samsung Android version, if Samsung doesn't provide any additional API for this (which I bet) you can't modify system sheet/dialog

Comment: hum. I open some apps with 'share' function from my samsung device. The icon from the share sheet has been changed. if api have is private. i think they customize the sharing menu